# Dynamic importing component in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, dynamic-import

I want to split the bundle based on routes. So tried with dynamic importing in react-router as shown below, but no luck. Also tried the same with loadable, in loadable there is flickering when hydrate starts. It removed entire dom and added again. How to acheive this?, i dont want to bundle everything in a single file, similarly i have 10 different routes.

```js
// With dynamic import
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/details/:name/:id',
    component: import(/* webpackChunkName: "details" */ '../components/details')
  }
];
```

```js
// With Loadable
const Details = loadable(() => import('../components/details'), { ssr: true });
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/details/:name/:id',
    component: Details
  }
];
```

Comment: Add the scope in which you're mapping through `routes` and creating react-router `Route`s.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `component` prop in `Route`, you might use `render` prop which takes a function, and therefore allow you to implement some logic inside

```
const routes = [
{
 path: '/details/:name/:id',
 render: () => condition ? import(/* webpackChunkName: "details" */ '../components/details') : import(/* webpackChunkName: "component2" */ '../components/component2')
}
];
```

Comment: it is not working, getting error in SSR. Becoz it will return Promise